# Super class to call a function from a subclass

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I have a base class with two methods, "A" and "B".

Method "B" calls "A" in the base. Then I have a subclass which overrides "A" method. When I call the method "B" from subclass the method "A" from base is called.

Is there a way the super calls the overridden method from the subclass?

```
export class SuperClass {
    A(param: any): string {
        return "A called from base";
    }

    B(param: any): string {
        let value = this.A(param);
        console.log(value);

        return "B called from base";
    }
}

export class SubClass extends BaseClass  {
    A(param: any): string {
        return "A called from subclass";
    }
}

// create a subclass
let bInstance = new B();
bInstance.B(someParam); // I want to call the overriden A in the subclass
```

PD: "A" in the base class needs to have its own implementation, can't be abstract

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> bInstance.B(someParam); // I want to call the overriden A in the
>   subclass

It will call the overridden method `A` in the subclass because `this` will be pointing to the instance of `SubClass` and JS will be looking for a method `A` on this instance first. So this code:

```
B(param: any): string {
    let value = this.A(param);
    console.log(value);
```

should log `"A called from subclass";`

Comment: Oh... dude, you're right... my bad, I was just creating an instance of the base class...